# php gettext debugging

Tags: php, debugging, gettext

I have a problem with gettext, on my local testing machine it works like a charm, on production server it doesn't.
gettext seems to avoid displaing any kind of error, either it works or it doesn't.

Is there any way to debug, or to force it to log everything it does?

thanks

Comment: error reporting is true? there is nothing in the error log?

Comment: I tried setting php to display each and every error

Comment: I agree : For that gettext is really a pain !
That's a shame there is no option to show the slightest log message !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anybody encounter this from search engines. In my case the problem was that php didin't had any locale installed! Without locale it can't work, so always check this as sometime updating php resets locale.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your production server was not built with

```
--with-gettext[=DIR]
```

You can check if it's enabled by checking `phpinfo()` output. You should find a section **gettext**, if it was built-in.